# Dispatcher has detected a cyclic routing causing stability problems in phalcon

Tags: phalcon

When i am trying to access any controller following error is coming.

My code is working fine in my local machine where Apache server is running.

When i am uploading same code in my server machine and try to use. Below given error is coming.

In my server NGINX web sever is running.

> Dispatcher has detected a cyclic routing causing stability problems
>
> #0 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher->_throwDispatchException('Dispatcher has ...',
> 1)
>
> #1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->dispatch()
>
> #2 /home/vtermina/public_html/api/v2/public/index.php(31): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()
>
> #3 {main}

Comment: If only it told you what caused the cycle.

Comment: Maybe you have a misconfigured ACL? What route are you trying to access? What code do you have inside your destination controller? Show us some examples!

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs in two cases:

- you have declared two same named routes
- you are dispatching actions from `A` to `B` to `A` couple of times.

If secont, it is possible that your NGNIX configuration prevets Phalcon from receiving full list of parameters. But it will be difficult to guess it out w/o any code and configuration.